# Docker containers with volume mounting exits immediately on using docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I am using `docker-compose up` command to spin-up few containers on AWS AMI RHEL 7.6 instance. I observe that in whichever containers there's a volume mounting, they are exiting with status `Exiting(1)` immediately after starting and remaining containers remain up. I tried using `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true`, but it didn't help. Surprisingly, the set-up works fine in another instance which basically I am trying to replicate in this new one.
The stopped containers are Fabric v1.2 peers, CAs and orderer.

Docker-compose.yml file which is in root folder where I use `docker-compose up` command

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  gcsbc:
    name: gcsbc

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    extends:
      file: fabric/docker-compose.yml
      service: ca.org1.example.com
```

fabric/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

networks:
  gcsbc:

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem

    ports:
      - '7054:7054'
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts/channel/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerorg1
    networks:
      - gcsbc
    hostname: ca.org1.example.com
```

Comment: Did you check the logs of that container which exiting???

Comment: Have you tried using `docker logs containername` to find out why it's failing? Or tried removing bits from your dockerfiles to see which section of code is causing the failure.

Comment: Also posting more details about your images/containers/dockerfiles/composer.yml would be of help

Comment: As mentioned in the description, the volumes: section is leading to this error. The logs show that it is not able to find the mounted files which I think is due to unsuccessful mounting.

Comment: can you add compose file

Comment: updated the question with compose file snippet